# Manually start ray cluster

Tags: python, ray

I have start ray as a head node in one machine: ray start --head --port=6379

And when I tried to connect another node to the head, I get this error message:

:~/dev_root$ ray start --address='10.50.131.250:6379' --redis-password='5241590000000000'
Local node IP: 10.50.131.67
[2021-10-20 21:28:14,052 C 18965 18965] global_state_accessor.cc:342: Failed to get system config within the timeout setting.

```
*** StackTrace Information ***
    ray::SpdLogMessage::Flush()
    ray::RayLog::~RayLog()
    ray::gcs::GlobalStateAccessor::GetSystemConfig()
    __pyx_pw_3ray_7_raylet_19GlobalStateAccessor_41get_system_config()
    _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords
```

I have tried to google any similar issues, but I cannot find anything.

Anyone has any idea what it is about?

Answer (score 1):

finally, I get it working now. The issue is the ports. It requires more ports to be opened, i.e.

```bash
--ray-client-server-port=10101 --min-worker-port=10102 --max-worker-port=10999
```

for both the head and the workers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).